# Plot a data frame as a grouped bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

How best can I plot this dataset as a grouped bar plot as shown below?

[image: sample plot]

```
Zone       Oct      Nov        Dec
   1  554370.8 687899.0  702890.80
   2 1072629.8 899767.6 1058627.17
   3  660052.9 689939.9  543796.50
   4  104881.2 114328.2   86620.23
```

Comment: what is your definition of grouped bar plot ?

Comment: I would like to cluster my bar plot such that in the y-axis values in `Oct, Nov, Dec` are grouped by `Zone`

Comment: please look at https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more reshaped dataset.

```
zone   count month
1 1127071   Jan
2 1025269   Jan
3  196059   Jan
4   43535   Jan
1 1193999   Feb
2 1002110   Feb
3  156429   Feb
4   39396   Feb
```

Can I plot `count` as y and `month` as x but grouped by `zone`?

I have managed to write this:

```
ggplot(statLs, aes(month, count, fill=zone, group=zone)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack")
scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Jan", "Feb")) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "orange", "yellow", "grey"))
```

But this returns an error

```
Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

Answer (score 1):

First gather the data and then plot with `ggplot2`. Lets say your original data was called `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- gather(df, Month, val, -Zone)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=Zone, y=val, fill = Month)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: How about plotting `month` in the x axis but grouped by `zone`?